# Delphi update a joined query

Tags: sql, sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe4

The application is datasnap (with sqlite database). I run the following query against two tables (LOKACIJE and UPORABNIKI):

```
procedure TForm4.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ClientDataSet1.Close;
   ClientDataSet1.CommandText :='';
   ClientDataSet1.CommandText :=  'select  lokacije.[HOTEL_ID],'+
                                  '        lokacije.[NAZIV],'+
                                  '        uporabniki.[LOKACIJA_ID],'+
                                  '        uporabniki.[RESORT_ID],'+
                                  '        uporabniki.[HOTEL_ID],'+
                                  '        uporabniki.[UPORABNIK],'+
                                  '        uporabniki.[GESLO],'+
                                  '        uporabniki.[PRAVICE]'+
                                  '        from UPORABNIKI'+
                                  '        inner join LOKACIJE on uporabniki.lokacija_id=lokacije.lokacija_id '+
                                  ' where lokacije.[NAZIV] = :@NAZIV'+
                                  ' order by Uporabniki.[UPORABNIK]';
 ClientDataSet1.Params.ParamByName('@NAZIV').Value:= '' + Form2.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[3].Text + '' ;
 ClientDataSet1.Open;
end;
```

The query runs fine and gives me the desired results. However I would like to be able to edit and save the edited (or added) results of this query. The table that I want to update (or add the new record) is the UPORABNIKI. I do not need to write anything to the LOKACIJE table. How am I to accomplish this ?

Apart from saving new record I would like the query to fill automatically the values 
LOKACIJA_ID,RESORT_ID,HOTEL_ID as they are from the same table, when I click in the navigator the button 'insert'. UPORABNIKI is translated USERS table.

edit : Inverted the query as suggested

Comment: See [Creating Master-Detail Relationships](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Creating_Master-Detail_Relationships). With client datasets, the usual approach is to use [nested detail tables](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Using_Nested_Detail_Tables).

Comment: @TOndrej - dont have time to read through all embarcadero especially since they dont provide an example applicable in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a case in which `TDatasetProvider` is unable to produce the right command to update the tables involved. In this cases, what I do is to add a handler to the `TDatasetProvider.BeforeUpdateRecord` event. This event will let you handle each operation worked on the dataset and produce the needed SQL statements to propertly persist those operations in the data server.

You will have to write the UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT statements yourself, but you will also have absolute power about how the tables are updated. That´s why I always use this event and never rely on `TDatasetProvider` intrinsec update process.

Comment: please,can you give me an example of the UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT statements?

Comment: if I understand this correctly,I must place another query on my form, a query which will be triggered by TDatasetProvider.BeforeUpdateRecord and which shall service the UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT events ?

Comment: @user3181689: yes, that´s the idea. You can use another query component or run the statement directly over the connection component, when it supports that or any other way you like to run the statements.

Answer (score 1):

See the `OnGetTableName` event on the `TDatasetProvider`.

Also, I believe it would be better if you invert your query, i.e., use `... FROM UPORABNKI inner join LOKACIJE...`

Answer (score 0):

The OnGetTableName event from the TDataSetProvider has a var parameter called TableName. You should assign it to 'UPORABNIKI'.

Also, usually TDataSetProvider thinks that the table you use on the FROM clause is the one you want to update, so, if you change your query, the above event might not even be needed.

Hope that helps,
Marco

Comment: what must I write in DatasetProvider on getTablename ? TableName :='UPORABNIKI'; ?